# Emacs opens files in a new frame when opened with "open -a"

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

I want to be able to invoke Emacs from the command-line, and either start graphical Emacs if it isn't running or visit a file in an already running Emacs. I tried to do this with `emacsclient` which I know is the "right" way to do this, but I had a lot of problems with it on OS X, it would randomly crash, or the `emacs --daemon` process would hang during shut down or rebooting the machine, and general flakiness. While I'd like to get that to work, at the moment `open -a` actually works much better, except for this one problem I'll describe below:

Using `open -a` like this:

```
$ open -a Emacs file.txt
```

will start Emacs if it's not running, and visit the file. But if I do this when the current buffer isn't `*scratch*` the file is opened in a new frame (ie a new system window).

Here's an example session:

```
$ open -a Emacs file.txt
```

This starts Emacs and opens file.txt, so there's a single frame with this buffer in it. If I switch to the `*scratch*` buffer, and do this:

```
$ open -a Emacs file1.txt
```

It opens this file in the same frame. Now there's a single frame with this file open, and if I do this:

```
$ open -a Emacs file2.txt
```

It opens a new frame, resulting in two frames open at once.

I've tried fiddling with command-line args to Emacs using the `--args` switch to `open`, but this doesn't seem to work for subsequent calls, for instance:

```
$ open -a Emacs --args --eval='(print "foo")'
$ open -a Emacs --args --eval='(print "bar")'
```

This only prints "foo" in the message buffer... the second time Emacs is just brought to the foreground but no message is printed.

I'm not sure how `open` communicates with applications that are already running, does anyone know how I could find out? Or is there some way to get a much more detailed log of what's going on than the `Messages` buffer? Nothing interesting is printed to that buffer during the session above, so I don't know how I could hack some Emacs Lisp to do what I want...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know a thing about OSX so I can't provide anything concrete.  If I were to debug this, though, I would throw some syntax error into `find-file` and then set `debug-on-error` to t and check out the stack trace for some clue as to how Emacs is being invoked.  Adding an error to `find-file` could be as simple as copying the function definition to the lisp scratch buffer and adding a call to `error` in it (e.g. `(error "cause stack trace")`. NEVER CHANGE THE SOURCE FILE FOR `find-file` -- always do this in a scratch bufer!

Comment: @Joe Thanks! That's a pretty good idea, I'll keep it in mind for the future. I actually ended up trying to use `emacsclient` again, and starting it with `(server-start)` in my `init.el` seems to be working better than `emacs --daemon` at boot up, which is what I had been trying the first time I tried `emacsclient`.

Answer (score 28):

Answer is here:
[emacs variable to "open with" in original frame](https://superuser.com/questions/277956/emacs-variable-to-open-with-in-original-frame)

It's a change to the default settings in newer versions of emacs.  Add:

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

to .emacs file.

Very happy to have found this.

Comment: This was very helpful! Together with an alias `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app $1` things seems to work fine! Note that I start the server in my init, to have emacs available for git for example.