# Emacs (setq ns-pop-up-frames nil) not working

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 under Ubuntu 13.10

I need Emacs to open all new files in the the same window.

According to [EmacsWiki: One Window](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneWindow), I added

```
(setq pop-up-windows nil)
```

To my configuration file, but it didn't work.

I tried [how to make emacs open all buffers in one window (debian/linux/gnome)'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278820)'s suggestion:

```
(custom-set-variables '(pop-up-frames nil))
```

But it didn't work as well.

I tried [emacs variable to “open with” in original frame's answer](https://superuser.com/a/370659)'s suggestion:

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

But it didn't work.

This should be something simple to configure, quite annoyhing..

Appreciate your help,

Amitai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was some kind of change in how this behaviour is customized around version 24.* (not quite sure). I think `display-buffer-alist` is the thing you are looking for.

So something along the lines of

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("^[^\\*].*[^\\*]$" display-buffer-same-window) t)
```

might work for you. The regexp is the one that a buffer name will be matched against (this one assumes file names don't start and end with asterisks).

See also the documentation for `display-buffer`, which decides where to display a buffer. There are several functions there along the lines of `same-window`, `reuse-window`, `pop-up-{window,frame}`.

By the way, `ns-*` functions are for OS X, they probably won't do anything on linux.